# How can I either move the nav bar down or create more space for the header? Theme - Ajaira

Tags: themes, css

I entered a header image as a logo to the theme ajaira. Although the image has the right size, it won't fit onto the page.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what's the link?

Comment: Hi gdaniel, the link is:

https://life-decodedcom.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the background image was added to the  tag inline. You will need to change the following:

Locate your template file (probably header.php) which has the tag  Inside style="" remove `background-size: cover` and replace it with `background-size:auto 100%` then add `background-position: center`

This will let the background image stretch to the height of the element and adjust it's width automatically, and then it will center the image.

You can achieve the same thing by editing the style.css file, and adding the above to header.site-header but you will need to use the !important tag if you want it to override the inline styles. Something like:

```
header.site-header{
    background-size:auto 100% !important;
    background-position: center
}
```

I modified your page in the browser. Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: That is awesome, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can look at the CSS class used for the header image, you can use some customized CSS to change the height of that class. Assuming class name of 'header_image':

```
.header_image {height:300px;}
```

Adjusting the value as needed. You would place that CSS in the 'additional CSS' area of the theme customization (if available). There are also plugins that will allow you to add CSS to your theme. Plus the route of creating a Child Theme and putting your custom CSS in there.

Comment: It's actually an element style and CSS background image. He needs custom CSS for background-size and background-position, and a height adjustment for one of the divs within the header section. A bit surprising the theme isn't set up better for this kind of thing, though I don't of course know how the example was put together.